# Loading a listbox with database items (LINQ) (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, linq, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-phone

edit: updated code

I'm having trouble understanding how to load data from my database into a List or collection and bind it to a ListBox.

This is in my ViewModel.

```
// List of Album set as the data source for Listbox
private ObservableCollection<Album> _albums;
public ObservableCollection<Album> Albums
{
    get { return _albums; }
    set { _albums = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

        private void AddAlbum()
    {
        albumDB.Albums.InsertOnSubmit(new Album
        {
             AlbumName = AlbumName,
             AlbumTimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
             IsPrivate = IsPrivate,
             Password = Password
        });
        SaveChangesToDB();
        LoadAlbums();
    }

    private void LoadAlbums()
    {
        Albums = new ObservableCollection<Album>(albumDB.Albums);

    }
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="AlbumList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumName}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I don't think I need to post the model but if so I can!

Comment: Have you attached viewmodel to the view (setting it as veiw's `DataContext`)?

Comment: I did attach the viewmodel to the view.

Also, thanks Grant. I'll edit it.

Comment: Try to change textblock binding to `Text="{Binding}"`, just for the sake of debugging, to see it's actual `DataContext` at runtime.

Comment: How do I check its datacontext at runtime? Sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: as I said in my prev comment change binding that way, then your textblock will display the actual object type referenced by `DataContext`. It should be like `your.namespace.Album` if `DataContext` has been set correctly

Comment: You mean within the app itself it will show "your.namespace.Album" or somewhere debugging it I can find it? (I don't know how to check values of xaml properties when they're only declared in the view, sorry.)

Comment: in the app it self. If textblock is blank, means there is nothing in `DataContext`. Could you show how did you attach the viewmodel?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I didn't realize it at first, but I have two listboxes in my xaml code. The first one's datasource isn't bound to the viewmodel because there's only supposed to be one. So yeah, technically the data source wasn't set correctly and that's why it wasn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your **DataTemplate** like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumName}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Because the `DataContext` of ListBox.ItemTemplate is **Album**. So what you should do is bind AlbumName to your TextBlock, but not AlbumModel.AlbumName.

Comment: Thanks, I did change that. Unfortunately, it is still not working.

Comment: So you can check the code you use the viewmodel. and debug the code of LoadAlbums()

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get help with the C# because I just started learning LINQ yesterday and am not positive as to what I am doing. :(

Comment: Yeah. I see your LINQ. You can debug the LoadAlbums() method to see if the DataSource is Empty.

Comment: Okay, tbh I'm not the best at debugging..BUT, I did just find out that all of my items were NULL in the DB because I forgot to set the binding mode to twoway when adding text from textboxes.

My datasource is not empty, but, it is still not working. :(

Comment: So I think the issue is in your viewmodel. Debug it and check why the properties is NULL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58207/discussion-between-user3007447-and-chris-shao).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<ListBox x:Name="AlbumList" ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumName}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

all the best :)